# C++11 Magic to test and assign from pointer if not nullptr

Tags: c++11

Okay, I believe in defensive programming.  I assume that if I get a pointer it might be null (especially when using GSOAP).  Therefore before I try to use the value of the pointer, I always check to make sure the pointer is not null.

In my current code, this is leading to a lot of nearly identical statements.

```
if (res->A) {
    item.out_trace->a = *res->A;
}
if (res->B) {
    item.out_trace->b = *res->B;
}
if (res->C) {
    item.out_trace->b = *res->C;
}
```

I realize that I could always go and define a macro for this, but I am wondering if there is a neat C++11 trick to do that.  I would love something like the C# `??`

```
// Set y to the value of x if x is NOT null; otherwise, 
// if x = null, set y to -1. 
int y = x ?? -1;
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no reason to do this in your code; taking the address of a NULL pointer is perfectly valid and safe. Or did you mean `*res->A`?

Comment: @Lightness Yep.  I meant `*res->A`.... It's been a long week... fixed now.

Comment: The ternary operator, would do what ?? does : `item.out_trace->a = res->A ? *res->A : -1;`

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou I thought of using the ternary operator in a macro to make it easier to read.

Comment: Personally, I would just convert the three `if` statements into oneliners, and be done with it. The only repetition in the code is the repetition of `res->X`, which does not justify resorting to the dark arts. And any macro/template magic will obscure what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a template like this would meet your need:

```
template<typename T>
T safe_get( T const *ptr, T defval = T{} ) {
    return ptr ? *ptr : std::move(defval);
}
```

It could be used like this:

```
item.out_trace->a = safe_get( rez->A );
```

Ideally it would be inlined and effectively zero-overhead (other than the inherent overhead of doing the safety check and having a branch, of course).

Comment: I would steal a page from `optional` and call it `value_or`.

Comment: What is the type of expression `*ptr ? <T&> : <T&&>` please?

Comment: I think the standard says it is `<T&&>`, in other words that is equivalent to `ptr ? std::move(*ptr) : std::move(defval)`. In other words, you accidentally move from `*ptr`.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: No you cannot accidentally move, not from a `T const &` anyway.